# getting variable name change in android using gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am making an android application using google Gson to parse to and from json classes that I have in other project.
I have a class Person which contains attributes like:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName; 
    private String lastName;

public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String name) {
    this.firstName = name;
}
}
```

But when I'm debugging in the `MainActivity.java` I see a or b as attribute names instead of **firstName** and **lastName**, and that's make the json text be:

```
{a:"someName", b:"someLastName"}
```

does anyone know's why is this and how can I fix it?

class `Person.java` is located in a separated project. I think that my project can't see the source code and that would be the reason.

I'm kind of lost here.
Thank you

Comment: Are you using ProGuard? If so, annotate your member variables with `@SerializedName("attributeName")`.

Comment: Why is Person in another project?? copy to your project and attribute in json must have same as variable in class to use Gson.

Comment: not using ProGuard.
Person is in another project not by choice, is mandatory to be like that